# Live Screen Monitoring With Python3 Pytesseract

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, ocr, python-tesseract

I am working on a python3 project on windows 10, and I was wondering if anyone knew of anyway to pass an opencv screen grab through pytesseract? If not, is there any other OCR that you could?

Here is the  code for the opencv screen grab:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageGrab
import cv2



while True:
    screen =  np.array(ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0,40,800,640)))
    cv2.imshow('window', cv2.cvtColor(screen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY))
    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: What do you mean *"pytesseract only appears to be for images"*? A screen grab is an image, surely? Maybe an image of what you are looking for would help...

Comment: Sorry for the confusing question, I've only been using python for a little over 2 months and I only know the basics. Do you mean like a screen shot of the screen grab?

Comment: Anything that clarifies the question will help - thanks.

Comment: Is that a little less confusing?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Why don't you pass the screen you have captured to `tesseract` and see if it can recognise the test on it?

Comment: I don't know how to do that, I'll add that to the question sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: It's no problem - we are all here to learn! And help.

Comment: Cool, thank you so much for helping me with my question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know very little about `pytesseract`, but this might get you started:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageGrab
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance, ImageFilter
from textblob import TextBlob

# Grab some screen
screen =  ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0,0,800,640))
# Make greyscale
w = screen.convert('L')

# Save so we can see what we grabbed
w.save('grabbed.png')

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(w)
correctedText = TextBlob(text).correct()

print(correctedText)
```

From this grab:

[image]

I got:

```
@ Terminal Shell Edit View Window Help

The writing is on the wall
```

Comment: Thank you! With some easy tweaking to fit my project this will be perfect!

Comment: Cool - good luck! There may be better examples and practices, try putting `[pytesseract]` with the square brackets into StackOverflow's **Search** box and see how other folks use it too.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it.